# EOF with tabulation regex

Tags: regex, eof, cat

Command `cat` not supports regex, I'm wish put domain address in `/etc/hosts` file with tabulation:

```
cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
10.1.1.3\tnode1
10.1.1.4\tnode2
EOF
```

I'm research for alternative that support regex.

By now, I'm solving this using two commands with a `echo`:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "10.1.1.3\tnode1" >> /etc/hosts'
sudo sh -c 'echo -e "10.1.1.4\tnode2" >> /etc/hosts'
```

Comment: Why would you need regex here?

Comment: This is a simple example, I have this necessity in other contexts, that tabulation are relevante (python script for example).

Comment: For more complex string operations you may want to use `sed` or `awk`.